# Split a pandas dataframe into equal of multiple dataframe and convert to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

Part of my program needs a certain kind of input. So I need to split a pandas dataframe into n multiple dataframes and convert to json without header for that input.
E.g. I have a dataframe like this

```
`import pandas as pd
myDf = pd.DataFrame(['banana', 'apple', 'watermelon','grapes','cherry', 'blueberry'], columns=['fruit'])`
```

which looks like this

```
`        fruit
0      banana
1       apple
2  watermelon
3      grapes
4      cherry
5   blueberry`
```

I need an output similar to l1 programatically

```
`import json
l1 = [['banana','apple', 'watermelon'], ['grapes', 'cherry', 'blueberry']]
print(json.dumps(l1, indent = 4))`
```

which should look like this as it should exclude the header 'fruit'

```
`[
    [
        "banana",
        "apple",
        "watermelon"
    ],
    [
        "grapes",
        "cherry",
        "blueberry"
    ]
]`
```

I spilt the dataframe

```
fruitList = np.array_split(myDf, 2)
```

then in for loop I tried this

```
`json.loads(fruitList_iter.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient='values'))`
```

but it's not giving me the expected result.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the underlying numpy array to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
out = json.dumps(myDf['fruit'].to_numpy().reshape(2, -1).tolist(), indent=4)
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "banana",
        "apple",
        "watermelon"
    ],
    [
        "grapes",
        "cherry",
        "blueberry"
    ]
]
```